# Linear transformation and direct sums

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification, linear-transformations, direct-sum

We consider the direct sum $E_1 \oplus E_2$ of vector spaces. Then proof that the transformation $E_1 \oplus E_2 \to E_1$ defined by $(u_1, u_2) \mapsto u_1$ is linear. Also the map $E_1 \to E_1 \oplus E_2$ given by $u \mapsto (u, \mathbf{0})$.

I don't know if my procedure is right. First, name $f$ to be the first linear transformation we have defined. Then $f(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{0})= \mathbf{0}$. Now take $u, v \in E_1 \oplus E_2$, $u = (u_1, u_2)$ and $v = (v_1, v_2)$. $f(u+v) = f(u_1 + v_1, u_2 + v_2) = u_1+v_1 = f(u) + f(v)$. Lastly, let $\lambda \in K$, where $K$ is a field. Then $f(\lambda \cdot u) = f(\lambda \cdot u_1, \lambda \cdot u_2) = \lambda \cdot u_1 = \lambda \cdot f(u)$.

Any comment or correction would be welcomed!

Comment: Your procedure  is right. You can prove the second part in a similar manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote the said map by $T$. Consider any $u,v\in E_1$. Then for any scalar $\alpha$

$T(\alpha u+v)=(\alpha u+v,0)=\alpha (u,0)+(v,0)=\alpha Tu+Tv,$

which shows that $T$ is linear.